# Store result of a for loop in Perl as a single variable

Tags: perl, for-loop

I'm currently printing a result in the for loop itself:

```
for (@data1, @data2, @data3) {
    print "$_" . " ";
}
```

Instead I want to process the loop quietly and store the entire result of the for loop as a variable, then print it separately like so:

```
print "$forloopresult";
```

How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, I'd just use a [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
my $foo = join(' ', @data1, @data2, @data3);
print "$foo "; # space at the end to emulate your for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable and append the data at each step:

```
my $result = "";
for (@data) {
    $result = $result."$_ ";
}

print $result;
```

Comment: You could also use `.=` as in `$result .= "$_ "`

Comment: @JimDavis, right, I am intentionally using more explicit syntax. Just to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to keep the `print` statement but have the text go to a variable instead of to a console then that is also possible. You can print to a scalar variable if you pass a reference to that variable instead of a file name

It looks like this. I have declared `$forloopresult` and passed `\$forloopresult` as the third parameter of `open`. The output of `Data::Dump` shows the result

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @data1 = qw/ a b c /;
my @data2 = qw/ aa bb cc /;
my @data3 = qw/ aaa bbb ccc /;

my $forloopresult;
open my $fh, '>', \$forloopresult or die $!;

for ( @data1, @data2, @data3 ) {
    print $fh "$_ ";
}

dd $forloopresult;
```

#### output

```
"a b c aa bb cc aaa bbb ccc "
```